# Selenium Actions moveToElement on Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80 on ubuntu doesnot work

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selected an element and wanted --> physically move the mouse cursor over it.

tried using Actions class provided with selenium.method used is `moveToElement()`.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Used driver version is  ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90.

Expected :- Physical Cursor Must move to element location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Chrome 75.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
element.click();
```

That real solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using seems correct. Looks either you need to wait as it quicky moves to next statement

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
try{
     Thread.sleep(6000);
}
catch(Exception ex){

}
```

OR

Your element is not ready yet you need to wait for it like below:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")))

actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Comment: Hi shubham,the real cause of this issue is ubuntu linux. Code works perfectly on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with windows too, using chrome `75.0.3770.90` and chrome driver `75.0.3770.8`.
Try to do this :

```
actions.moveToElement(element).release().build().perform();
```

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks.I will try out your code if that works,I will mark it as solved and accepted answer.